# How to enable Axis (Web Services) logging in unix server?

Tags: axis

Im trying to enable the axis in the unix server. But didnt know how to do it. Found this link "http://maximodev.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-enable-web-services-logging.html" but didnt find the file(common-logging.properties) file.

Any help is greatly appriciated.